# HTML Encoding Quoted Printable- Javax Mail

Tags: java, html, utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I am trying to add a html body part to a email and send. I am using the charset as 'text/html; charset=utf-8' and Content-Transfer-Encoding as "quoted-printable". When downloading the email and looking at the html, I want the ' . ', ' " ', ' } ' to be be ascii encoded as '=2E', '=22', '=7D' respectively, but it stays the same without any encoding.

for example, https://google.com, should be encoded as https://google=2Ecom, when the link is in a html

My code as follows:

```
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
    message.setSubject(subjectLine);
    message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    message.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
    Transport.send(message);
```

I tried using ISO-8859-1, but the downloaded emails stays the same without any encoding. Can you please tell me what charset and Content-Transfer-Encoding should I use to make the characters encoded?

Comment: quoted-printable does not require those characters to be encoded.  Why do you want to encode them?  Are you trying to hide them from spam filters?

Comment: Bill Shannon: I am not trying to hide them for spam filters, I am getting raw emails in that format.. I am trying to replicate the same format which I receive in production for my testing purpose. If the format is different qa, env is failing to process them

Comment: If it's just for testing, construct the raw message content by hand.  [PreencodedMimeBodyPart](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/PreencodedMimeBodyPart.html) might be helpful.